# Is there some Google Talk Addon that I can use to group people in my Google Talk chat list?

Tags: plugins, pidgin, google-talk

I know Pidgin can do this, but I do not want to use Pidgin due to its interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTalk uses the formerly Jabber protocol, now named Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP).

I don't see anything wrong with Pidgin interface, actually I use it in my openSUSE desktop at work without problems.

Since interface is a problem and I can't decide for you, you should really check XMPP capable softwares. Wikipedia [list of XMPP client software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XMPP_client_software) is a great start.

Comment: you mean any XMPP capable software can work as Google Talk??

Comment: Yes. I dont guarantee that you use the same settings across all software, but as long as you connect to gtalk servers with a XMPP capable client, you can use your gtalk account with no problem. I recommend reading some tutorials in pidgin to connect to gtalk (gmail servers) and see if they apply to your XMPP chosen software in the list I provided.